# Seeking New York Neighborhoods Boundaries?

Tags: data, coordinates, united-states, boundaries

I need a source of New York neighborhoods boundaries coordinates, I need to draw polygons around them just like this page is doing to Wingate, Brooklyn. 
https://www.exrny.com/listings/121719/2-bed-in-east-flatbush-ny

I spent days looking on Google, the best I could find was api.maponics.com/sample, but they just give away ZIP boundaries on the sample and zip codes sometimes include more than one neighborhood.

Comment: Can you better specify your question? You need the boundary coordinates of New York, or the boundary coordinates of administrative areas adjacent to New York?

Comment: I need boundaries of each New York neighborhood, the link shows an example of Wingate, Brooklyn.

Comment: If you seek open data then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first return when you google *new york neighboorhood gis shapefile* returns https://data.cityofnewyork.us/City-Government/Neighborhood-Tabulation-Areas/cpf4-rkhq which has a shapefile download option. I see a bunch of other links to them as well.